# Cannot connect to the MS SQL Server 2014 from a remote machine via named pipes

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, sql-server

I installed MS SQL Server 2014 on a machine that had an MS SQL Server 2012 default instance.

On the local machine, I can connect to both instances using named pipes. However, from a remote client, I can only connect to the default instance using named pipes. I can connect to both instances remotely if I use TCPIP. I do not understand why I cannot connect to the named instance remotely.

Any ideas? I have checked the usual configuration etc.

Answer (score 1):

Verify your remote named pipe connection string, for a named instance the format is

`\\<computer_name>\pipe\MSSQL$<instance_name>\sql\query`

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189307(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help. This was my first named instance setup.

Comment: I'm happy to help.  Please let me know if that does the trick for you, otherwise we'll keep at it until solved.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob, this did the trick. I got a bit confused. On the PC where I have SQL Server named instance installed, I can use<computer_name>\<instance_name> and that worked. So without thinking, I was trying the same on my client PC connecting to the server. What I do not understand, is at work they have many many SQL Server Instances on different servers and we never have to use  \\<computer_name>\pipe\MSSQL$<instance_name>\sql\query. We only use <computer_name>\<instance_name>.

Comment: I'm not sure from what you said, but I would guess that it's a TCP/IP thing vs. Named Pipes.

Answer (score -1):

Google for: ms sql connect via tcp/ip site:microsoft.com

One of the first links leads to:
[Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks the TCP was working as expected but the named instance did not. I am learning about SQL Server.